# How to change the displayed name of a folder added to IFileDialog using AddPlace

Tags: c++, windows-11, ifiledialog

I've implemented my own File Dialog using the IFileDialog interface, and I am adding Places to the file dialog. I need to change the displayed name of a place to my own text, because if I have two places that happen to have the same name, they are impossible to tell apart. For example:

- Place 1: Name = "My application files"; Path = "C:\Users\Me\OneDrive\Documents\MyAppName"
- Place 2: Name = "Shared application files"; Path = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\MyAppName"

However, Adding a place only shows the last folder name - so both these places appear under the "Application Links" heading as "MyAppName". Obviously I need to differentiate between these - ideally I would like the Place's name to be displayed.

My code to add a single Place is as follows (error checking removed for clarity):

```
        // Code above here sets nameW to the Place name, and pathW to its full path
        // These are both CStringW variables

        // Create the IShellItem for the folder 
        CComPtr<IShellItem> folder;
        SHCreateItemFromParsingName(pathW, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&folder);

        // This section is trying to change what is displayed... but doesn't work!
        PROPVARIANT pv = {0};
        PropVariantInit(&pv);
        pv.vt = VT_LPWSTR;
        pv.pwszVal = nameW.GetBuffer();
        // Here, I have tried various other properties such as PKEY_FileDescription, PKEY_FolderNameDisplay, etc. 
        SHSetTemporaryPropertyForItem(folder, PKEY_FileName, pv);

        // Add the place
        _FileDialog->AddPlace(folder, FDAP_TOP);
```

Can anyone tell me if / how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [AddPlace() documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-addplace):

> `SHSetTemporaryPropertyForItem` can be used to set a temporary **`PKEY_ItemNameDisplay`** property on the item represented by the `psi` parameter. The value for this property will be used in place of the item's UI name.

So, change `PKEY_FileName` to `PKEY_ItemNameDisplay` instead.

Comment: Well, doesn't that make me look stupid. Pretty sure I'd tried that one first, and it didn't work... I obviously had another bug in there which was preventing my early attempts from working, nothing to do with the display name...  Thanks!